# Regex with exception of specific word of path

Tags: regex, exception, path, cpu-word

I need to replace image URL with a dummy image URL. I'm currently having a problem to exclude paths that have `ignore` file name.

I've successfully implemented regex that match these two paths:

`images/image-filename.png` and `../images/image-filename.png`

with this following regex:

```
..\/images\/(.*?)\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)|images\/(.*?)\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)
```

However, I'd like to exclude any path with `ignore` word in the file name, for example:

```
images/image-filename-ignore.png
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option using a negative lookahead to assert that `ignore` does not appear as part of the filename:

```
images\/(?!.*ignore.*\.[^.]+).*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)
```

### Demo

But, you might also be able to proceed by actually matching the invalid filenames with `ignore`, and then logically excluding these matches:

```
images\/.*ignore.*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)
```

Comment: You might want to avoid enumerating `png` twice. `jpeg|jpg` could be simplified to `jpe?g`.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, but that would make the pattern a bit harder to read IMHO.  If I saw the above regex in application code, I at least wouldn't barf at the sight of it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you may likely want to add an `i` flag and word boundaries:

```
\/?images\/(?!.*\bignore\b)[^.]*\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|tiff|other_extensions)
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2hptOI/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/2hptOI/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---